# Server 2008 do not cache the CRL and OCSP

Tags: windows-server-2008, ocsp

Does somebody know, why my Windows Server 2008 R2 (not DC) do not cache the CRL and OCSP, the cahce is always empty?
The command `certutil -urlcache CRL` return nothing, unlike my local machine always has some records of crl url.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that certutil shows only current user's cache, not all machine and other users'.